# Play securesocial - developer environment and unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, playframework, securesocial

We are using securesocial module for authentication in Play 2 application.

I have two questions concerning this module.

Firstly, is there an easy way to disable the authorization checking in out development environment, preferably w/o commenting all `@SecureSocial.SecuredAction` annotations.

Secondly, what is the preferred way to unit test methods that use securesocial in Java? For example I have a call to `ctx().args.get(SecureSocial.USER_KEY);` in controller for getting the identity. If I would want to unit test this method, how can I mock out this identity? Or maybe secure social has some utility classes that can help unit testing?

Comment: For you first question, I think it is a bad idea to disable the authentication and authorization part of an application to develop it. This might result in security holes and unexpected behaviour. Can't you use a developpement login / social user?

Comment: You got a point there that it may create security holes. Mainly I wanted to disable it temporary because I wanted to test REST interface that we are creating and it is just annoying to copy-paste authorization cookie to http-requester, otherwise my application is denying access to my REST interface (and rightfully so)

Comment: Perhaps something in PlayFramework's onStart method in Global.scala to inject a type of Action that's used for all of your routes.

Answer (score 0):

We decided to create method `getUser` in our controller and then in unit-tests we are using http://www.javassist.org/ library to remove securesocial annotations and also to change return value of `getUser` to some mock that is created in test classes.